# CSS :after fails in IE8, but only after adding a reference to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

It's taken me a few hours to track this issue down and I'm a bit shocked by what I am seeing.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
        <style>
            a:after {
                content: attr(data-content);
            }
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>
        <a id="targetElement" href="http://www.google.com">Hello World</a>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("targetElement").setAttribute("data-content", "moo");
    </script>
</html>
```

The above example works appropriately in IE8. When viewed, the word 'moo' is appended to the end of targetElement:

[image]

Now, lets spice things up a little bit by reference jQuery via the CDN. Add the following line of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
```

such that the entire example reads as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
        <style>
            a:after {
                content: attr(data-content);
            }
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>
        <a id="targetElement" href="http://www.google.com">Hello World</a>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("targetElement").setAttribute("data-content", "moo");
    </script>
</html>
```

refresh IE8 and observe that the word moo has been dropped, but the element retains its data-content attribute:

[image]

I... I don't understand. I thought jQuery was supposed to be helping me out with cross-browser compatibility... but here it is wrecking shop.

Any ideas on how I can trouble shoot this? Or work around?

Comment: Is that IE8? It looks like IE9.

Comment: If you look in the screenshots you can see I have set my browser and document mode to IE8 and IE8 standards.

Comment: Oh I see now. Have you tried in _real_ IE8? There are many problems with after and pseudo selectors that maybe are not being emulated "properly"...Have you tried another version of jQuery?

Comment: I'll download it and double-check just to placate, but I have not experienced any issues with using IE's built-in emulation in the past. It would seem to defeat the point if their developer tools weren't emulating their old browsers properly. I'll report back in a few.

Comment: @SeanAnderson You do realize we are talking about Microsoft here, right?  Also, anything from the js console?

Comment: I just tried it with changing the `data-content` attribute to `title` and it works in IE8 compatibility for me: http://jsbin.com/iyizuv/4/edit  maybe you need an HTML5 boilerplate

Comment: @elclanrs I've confirmed that regular ol' IE8 renders the same as IE10 emulating IE8. Joseph: Enabling compat view in my IE8 browser does not cause anything to be rendered. Could you please provide a screenshot if its working for you? I'd be interested in seeing if I can spot the difference.

Comment: @SeanAnderson sorry... not compatibility view.  I'm running the emulated IE8 in IE10 just like you.  That demo uses the title attribute rather than the HTML5 attribute data-*.  It should work for you too.

Comment: @JosephMarikle Your example works properly when viewed inside of jsbin, but does not work in a plain page. http://i.imgur.com/pBDsEEh.png Curious..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32599/discussion-between-joseph-marikle-and-sean-anderson)

Comment: does it have to be 'data-content' ? what about using 'data-value' ?

Comment: I'm able to reproduce the issue using attr(title). It is not limited to data-content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright! I spoke with Joseph Marikle in chat and we worked through a large amount of examples attempting to track down the issue.

I have good news and I have bad news. The bad news first -- I don't know exactly what the hell is going on. The good news? I've got work arounds!

So, first off, if your element is on the page at design-time (not dynamically generated) then, as long as the element's attribute exists, the css should work.

E.g.:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
        <style>
            a:after {
                content: attr(title);
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a id="targetElement" title="hi" href="http://www.google.com">Hello World</a>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById("targetElement").setAttribute("title", " moo");
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-2.2.1.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This example works because targetElement has the title attribute defined. The title is set to moo at run time and the css reflects this by showing content as 'moo.'

If you remove the code title="hi", you will not see moo. FURTHERMORE, if targetElement is not on the page when the css is ran -- you will not see moo -- even if you generate targetElement with the title attribute existing.

If you want to dynamically generate your elements and have this css still work... I have a second workaround for you and this is the one I am currently using. The issue seems to be that IE8 isn't finding the element when it applies pseudo-selectors and it doesn't re-run its logic when the element shows up.

So, if you do something like..

```
node.children('a').attr('data-content', '[' + usedRackUnits + '/' + rackTooltipInfo.rackModel.rows + ']');

var addRule = function (sheet, selector, styles) {
    if (sheet.insertRule) return sheet.insertRule(selector + " {" + styles + "}", sheet.cssRules.length);
    if (sheet.addRule) return sheet.addRule(selector, styles);
};

addRule(document.styleSheets[0], 'li[rel="rack"] > a:after', "content: attr(data-content)");
```

This will modify your stylesheet at runtime and add a new CSS rule. This causes IE8 to re-apply the logic and, because the dynamic elements are on the page now, it finds them and applies the css appropriately. Woohoo! Stupid IE8.